# Pass AES ciphertext as parameter

Tags: c++, encryption, aes, encryption-symmetric, crypto++

I am trying to write 2 different functions to encrypt and decrypt the data using AES in cryptopp. I want to pass the ciphertext as a parameter to the decryption function. However on the decryption function, it recieves some special symbols as ciphertext & thus doesn't decrypt properly. Please help.

```
// -- AES encryption function ----------
void Security_packetAgent::encryption(char out[])
{ 
    std::string plaintext = out;
    std::string ciphertext = "";

    CryptoPP::AES::Encryption aesEncryption(key, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption cbcEncryption( aesEncryption, iv );

    CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfEncryptor(cbcEncryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink( ciphertext ) );
    stfEncryptor.Put( reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>( plaintext.c_str() ), plaintext.length() + 1 );
    stfEncryptor.MessageEnd();

    std::cout << "Cipher Text (" << ciphertext.size() << " bytes)" << std::endl;

    for( int i = 0; i < ciphertext.size(); i++ )
    {
        std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << (0xFF & static_cast<byte>(ciphertext[i])) << " ";
    }

    std::cout<<"\nMessage encrypted ...";
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    sprintf(out, "%s", ciphertext.c_str());
    printf("Final Data: %s : %s ", out, reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(ciphertext.c_str()));
}

// ---- AES decryption  ------------------
void Security_packetAgent::decryption(char out[])
{ 
    cout<<"\nCipher recieved: "<<out;
    std::cout<<"\nEntered decryption ..";
    std::string ciphertext = out;
    std::string decryptedtext;

    cout<<"\nCipher recieved: "<<reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>( ciphertext.c_str());
    CryptoPP::AES::Decryption aesDecryption(key, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Decryption cbcDecryption( aesDecryption, iv );

    CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfDecryptor(cbcDecryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink( decryptedtext ) );
    stfDecryptor.Put( reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>( ciphertext.c_str() ), ciphertext.size() );
    stfDecryptor.MessageEnd();

    std::cout << "Decrypted Text: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << decryptedtext;
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;    
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a code sample reproduces the problem? Also, show what the errors are and what was the output you expected.

Comment: dauphic answered your question. You might consider extending him the courtesy of marking his answer.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be constructing `std::string` out of a `char*`, if the `char*` is pointing to something that isn't a text string, such as encrypted data.

```
std::string ciphertext = out;
```

The construction of `ciphertext` is going to stop copying from `out` as soon as it reaches a 0 byte. Instead, you need to also pass in the **length** of the encrypted data and use the `std::string(const char* data, size_t size)` constructor.

```
std::string ciphertext(out, outSize);
```

Alternatively, you can also use the constructor taking a begin and end iterator.